# wrong color in geom_ribbon?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

testdf <- data_frame(time = c(ymd('2015-01-01'), ymd('2015-02-01'), ymd('2015-03-01')),
                     coef = c(1, 0, -1),
                     low_ci = c(-0.5, -0.25, -2),
                     high_ci = c(1.5, 0.5, -.5))

> testdf
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  time        coef low_ci high_ci
  <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2015-01-01     1  -0.5      1.5
2 2015-02-01     0  -0.25     0.5
3 2015-03-01    -1  -2       -0.5
```

Here I want to plot the time series of `coef`, using the `low_ci` and `high_ci` as confidence interval bands.

However, using the following code produces a surprising result

```
testdf %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = coef)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = low_ci, ymax = high_ci , alpha = 0.3, fill = 'blue'))
```

[image]

Since when blue is red?! What is the issue here?

Thanks!!

Comment: "Blue" is treated as a grouping value and gets a colour automatically, which happens to be the one you see. Whatever you type in `fill=` you'll get the same colour :)

Comment: damn, do you see a solution here? :)

Comment: add `+
  scale_fill_manual(values="blue")`

Comment: thanks, but what if I had another `fill` for the first `geom_`, say `geom_point()`. wouldnt they be confused?

Comment: thanks! perhaps you can post this as a solution? can you also fix the bogus legend here? does not make any sense at the moment lol! thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AntoniosK said, you can use the function `scale_fill_manual()`, but a second option is to put the parameter `fill = 'blue'` outside of the function `aes()` (same thing for the parameter alpha).
Like this :

```
testdf %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = coef)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = low_ci, ymax = high_ci), alpha = 0.3, fill = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! but how to fix the wrong label then? Alpha does not mean anything here

Comment: put `alpha = 0.3` outside of `aes()`. I edited the solution.

Comment: @demarsylvain thanks! last tweak, how can I now add a label that say coef is the black line? and the ribbon are confidence intervals?